# How to get specific elements from dictionary value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 699 lines and looks like this:

```
 .
 .
 '620': ['5', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', 'benign']
 '581': ['5', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', 'malignant']
 '618': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '?', '1', '1', '1', 'benign']
 .
 .
```

There are some question marks in random places. Every row has a class malignant or benign as the last element. To calculate this question marks, take the rows which has the same class. 
For example if a row has question mark on it and its class is benign only take rows which has benign, then find the all rows' index which is question mark's index. Then calculate average value of them them and assign it as question mark. Repeat this for all question marks.

I am a beginner. I couldn't figure out how to do it for weeks.

IT'S A COMPLICATED TASK BUT THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED.

```
dataFile = open('WBC.data','r').read()
dataDic = {i.split(',')[0]: i.split(',')[1:]  for i in dataFile.split('\n')}
print(dataDic)
indexsoruisareti_malignant=[] #soruişaretini oldugu indexler
indexsoruisareti_benign=[]
valueofindex_malignant=[]#malignant olan diğer satırlarda soru işaretinin 
oldugu sütunların elemanları
valueofindex_benign=[]
list1=[]

for key in dataDic:
    if '?' in dataDic[key] and 'malignant' in dataDic[key]:
        i = dataDic[key].index('?')  # attr(i+1)
        indexsoruisareti_malignant.append(i)
        t=list(set(indexsoruisareti_malignant))
    elif '?' in dataDic[key] and 'benign' in dataDic[key]:
        i = dataDic[key].index('?')  # attr(i+1)
        indexsoruisareti_benign.append(i)
        b=list(set(indexsoruisareti_benign))
print(t)
print(b)
for i in indexsoruisareti_malignant:
    for a in range(1,700):
        if '?' in dataDic[str(a)]:
            dataDic[str(a)].remove('?')
        list1.append(dataDic[str(a)][i])
        list2=[int(x) for x in list1]
    s=sum(list2)
print(s)
```

Comment: Show us your best attempt, please don't ask stackoverflow to do your homework :)

Comment: @wvanda it is not my homework . I am trying to improve my skills.And I am stucked.

Comment: what have you tried, show us some code/attempts

Comment: @wdanda edited my question.

Comment: Do all rows have the same number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

For data sets like these, it's recommended to use [pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/). The basic idea is to store the data in a dataframe and then partition the dataframe into one for benign and one for malignant.

Then for each dataframe, we look find the mean of the values and insert them into the missing entries ( `?`).

Lastly, we put them back together and convert it back to a dictionary (assuming that's the output format you require).

Below is the full code. (Ignore the `SettingWithCopyWarning`)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =  {'620': ['5', '1', '?', '2', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', 'benign'],
 '581': ['5', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', 'malignant'],
 '618': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '?', '1', '1', '1', 'benign']}

# Convert to pandas dataframe
df_all = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

# Divide into 2 dataframe (benign and malignant)
df_benign = df_all.loc[df_all[9] == 'benign']
df_malignant = df_all.loc[df_all[9] == 'malignant']

# Go through each data frame separately
for df in [df_benign, df_malignant]:
    for i in range(9):  # Iterate through each column
        # Find all values that are not '?' in the column
        values = [float(v) for v in df[i] if v != '?']
        col_mean = np.mean(values)  # mean of the column
        df.loc[df[i] == '?', i] = col_mean

# Combine the two dataframes        
df = pd.concat([df_benign, df_malignant])

# Convert back to dictionary
data_edited = df.to_dict(orient='index')
data_edited = {key: list(data_edited[key].values()) for key in data_edited.keys()}
```